# Find max changelist in client workspace other than p4 changes cmd

Tags: perforce

I need to find max changelist synced in my client workspace, one option is to use

```
p4 changes -m 1 @client_name
```

But since there are huge number of files in my branch, issueing `p4 changes` proves to be costly so I need some efficient way to solve this. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you're using `p4 changes`, it's that you're using it in a way that happens to be very inefficient.  If you go to the root directory of your client and ask it for the latest change you've synced into that directory tree, it's quite fast:

```
$ time p4 changes -m 1 ...#have
Change 2559333 on 2014/01/25 by joe@some-client

real    0m0.209s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.020s
```

Compare that to:

```
$ time p4 changes -m 1 @my-perforce-client
Change 2559333 on 2014/01/25 by joe@some-client

real    1m57.943s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.020s
```

Note that `p4 changes -m 1 ...#have` won't always show you the last change your client is synced to; it'll show you the last change that your client *has*.  For example, if your client is synced to change 123 but you later submitted change 456, `p4 changes -m 1 ...#have` will report change 456.  To work around this, it's usually advisable to use `p4 changes -m 10 ...#have` (or a sufficiently high `-m` value) and to then filter out your own changes.

Comment: And I don't know why the `@client` version is so slow, but I'd guess that it involves first querying the server first to determine what files are in the client's view.

Comment: The biggest issue though is that the first one does not do what you want.

Comment: @gsf Oops, that was careless of me.  My answer was primarily meant to address the performance issue.  I've updated my answer.